# Windows Phone 8 app development-Download code

Tags: javascript, css, html, windows-phone-8, download

Is there any possibility to use download attribute to download an image that is already in assets in Windows phone 8 app development using html5?

Comment: This question is unclear, can clarify it a bit?

Comment: I am developing windows phone 8 app using HTML5 and java script..I created a wallpaper collection app.I want the user to do download the pictures to their phone memory by clicking on a button. But the thing is, Visual Studio does not support using download attribute in anchor tag. Is there any alternative for that ?

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap or any other framework which enables native functionality inside HTML5 powered apps?

Comment: no..only visual studio

Answer (score 0):

[According to Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download), the download attribute is not yet supported by any version of IE, so I strongly suspect it won't work.

That said, in my experience, Visual Studio's HTML validation is very limited, so it's often best to ignore the warning and try it out!